# Preciso clicar no botão duas vezes para obter o valor

Tags: android, firebase

Alguem sabe o que fiz de errado, porque eu preciso clicar duas vezes no botão para ele puxar o valor.

```
package fabiohcnobre.jhotelcolonialdosnobres;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;
import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;

public class settingsActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    DatabaseReference myRef ;

    private String TAG;
    private String statusdareserva;

    private GoogleApiClient client;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_settings);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);




        Button btnbuscar = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_buscar);
        btnbuscar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                TextView textview1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TextView1);
                EditText editext1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edittext1);
                String status = "Falha";
                status = ProcuraReserva(editext1.getText().toString());
                textview1.setText("1"+ status);
            }
        });
    }


    public String ProcuraReserva(String codigodareserva){
        // Read from the database
        myRef = database.getReference("reserva/"+codigodareserva+"/status");
        myRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                String value = dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class);
                statusdareserva = value;
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError error) {
                statusdareserva = "Status com falha";
            }
        });

        return statusdareserva;

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O valor de `statusdareserva` é obtido no método `ProcuraReserva()` de forma assíncrona.
Repare que teve de criar um *ValueEventListener* para o receber.

Ou seja, a execução chega à linha `return statusdareserva;` antes de `statusdareserva` receber um valor em `onDataChange()` ou `onCancelled()`.

Entretanto o processo assíncrono(`database.getReference()`) termina e `statusdareserva` recebe um valor, que agora está disponível para ser devolvido em `return statusdareserva;`, quando clicar pela segunda vez.

Você tem de "setar" o TextView dentros do métodos `onDataChange()` é `onCancelled()`, pois é aí que ele está disponível quando for lido do banco de dados.

```
public void ProcuraReserva(String codigodareserva){
    // Read from the database
    myRef = database.getReference("reserva/"+codigodareserva+"/status");
    myRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            String value = dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class);
            textview1.setText("1"+ value);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError error) {
            textview1.setText("Status com falha");
        }
    });
}
```

Terá de declarar `textview1` como um atributo da *Activity* e iniciá-lo no método `onCreate()`

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda Ramaral deu para entender direito como funciona o codigo.

Answer (score 1):

Neste trecho, o processo esta entrando no metodo, e antes de terminar textview1.settext("1"+ status); ja foi ativado.

```
status = ProcuraReserva(editext1.getText().toString());
            textview1.setText("1"+ status);
```

Tenta colocar o textview uma variável global e fazer a mudança dentro do método ProcuraReserva();

teste também se esta entrando nos metodos onDataChange e onCancelled, não tenho certeza.

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda Icaro.